# Laravel how use value instead of full object with join in eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent, model

When I call eloquent:

```
$user = User::where('idUser', 1)->with(['privilege'])->first()->toArray();
```

It gives me:

```php
{
    "idUser": 1,
    "name": "UserName",
    "email": "UserName@gmail.com",
    "image": "https://image.com",
    "createdAt": "2019-05-07 15:43:47",
    "privilege": {
        "idPrivilege": 1,
        "name": "user"
    }
}
```

When I call Eloquent:

```
$user = User::where('idUser', 1)->with(['privilege:name'])->first()->toArray();
```

Element `privilege` in json is set to `null`, but when I call:

```
$user = User::where('idUser', 1)->with(['privilege:idPrivilege,name'])->first()->toArray();
```

It is as same as first call. How can I set element `privilege` to f.e. `user` (I just want a simple value instead of the full object of `Privilege`)?

I can use something like:

```
$user['privilege'] = $user['privilege']['name'];
```

But this one does not look so nice!

Using resource:

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'idUser' => $this->idUser,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'privilege' => $this->privilege['name'],
            'createdAt' => $this->created_at,
        ];
    }
```

In controller:

```
$user = User::where('idUser', 1)->with('privilege')->first();
return UserResource::make($user);
```

Gives:

```
{
"data": {
"idUser": 1,
"name": "UserName",
"email": "UserName@gmail.com",
"privilege": "user",
"createdAt": "2019-05-07 15:43:47"
}
}
```

How can i just return object instead of data{object} ?

Answer (score 0):

Try without the backets:

```
$user = User::where('idUser', $id)->with('privilege:name')->first()->toArray();
```

or this:

```
$user = User
        ::where('idUser', $id)
        ->with(['privilege' => function($query) {
            return $query->select('name');
        }])
        ->first()
        ->toArray();
```

But then, you could customize the response to return to your view using [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources). With this, you can have many different resources to use on the same elements and format the response to any of your needs.

Comment: Gives null as well.

Comment: @Martin I've added an alternative.

Comment: @Martin please, update your answer adding how are you using your resource to guide you to the solution.

Comment: When using this feature, you should always include the id column and any relevant foreign key columns in the list of columns you wish to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [HCK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7117697/hck)'s answer, you could use

```php
$user = User
        ::where('idUser', $id)
        ->with(['privilege' => function($query) {
            return $query->select('name');
        }])
        ->first()
        ->toArray();
```

To get what you need. Now, if you are already using [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources), and want to remove the outter `data` object, you can add the following in your `AppServiceProvider` `boot` method:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Perform post-registration booting of services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Resource::withoutWrapping(); // With this, your resources won't have the
                                     // outter data wrapping

    }
}
```

Just take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources#data-wrapping)!